# How to change where a branch was created from after the fact

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created a branch from another branch by mistake. My intention was to created it from master. Before I realise my mistake I've already commited and pushed that branch. Is there a way to change the "create from" process after a branch is created?

Comment: You can rebase.  Now that you've pushed, though, all the caveats about changing history and confusing other people's repos apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
git rebase --onto the-right-branch master my-branch
```

So, you are telling git to rebase your branch (discarding the revisions that make up the history of master) and put them on top of the-right-branch. my-branch will be set at the tip of that rebase. That doesn't change upstream for my-branch, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

If no-one else has pulled in that branch's changes, you can rebase your local branch and force push.  For simplicity, I prefer `git cherry-pick`

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
git cherry-pick <sha-of-original-commit>
git branch -u origin/<remote-branch>
git push --force
```

As William stated above, changing the history like this can cause confusion for other people who have already pull the change from your original branch.

Comment: This is probably the way I would do it too, although `rebase` might be easier. In all cases, if someone else has pulled since that commit, OP will need to fess up to the mistake. Pushing is a pretty permanent operation.

you might want to update to add `-force-with-lease` to the push command.